# Purpose of Sodium Fluoride (NaF) in Sodium Hydrogen Sulphate (NaHSO4) acid pickling solution?

Tags: metal

I am a proud home workshop electroplating fanatic, and the kit I sourced (from another country, with five weeks shipping) contained this bag of "Dry acide salts". I'm trying to source the chemicals locally to make up more of the solution and pickle bigger parts than the 5 litres (50g/litre) of solution I purchased provisions for.

Researching online, plenty of jewlers and people doing home metal preparation for plating are using Sodium Bisulphate but for some reason this kit contains Sodium Fluoride.

What purpose might it serve, can I ignore it? And in case it is useful, what is the ratio of NaF to NaHSO4?

[image: Dry Acid Salts / Acid Pickle]

Answer (score 2):

Sodium fluoride may react with small amounts of insoluble compounds like silica $\ce{SiO2}$ or silicates present in glass. It will produce some fluorosilicates which are soluble in water, according to the global equation : $$\ce{SiO2 + 6 NaF + 4 NaHSO4 -> Na2SiF6  +  4 Na2SO4 + 2 H2O}$$ Matter of fact, this reaction is the sum of two intermediate reactions, namely :
$$\ce{1)~~~~ HSO4^- + F- -> HF + SO4^{2-}}$$
$$\ce{2) ~~ 6 HF + SiO2 -> H2SiF6 + 2 H2O}$$

Comment: The weak hydrofluoric acid produced helps with rust removal. Where I live, a dilute hydrofluoric acid is sold, in some grocery stores, specifically for rust stain removal. The product is Whink Rust Stain Remover. Does a great job dissolving aluminum metal, as I discovered as a kid with a basement lab in the old days.

Comment: Does Maurice's answer suggest that the correct ratio is 1.5:1? (6NaF+4NaHSO4?)

Comment: If it was me, I would low ball the NaF: it is toxic and you do not need hazardous waste issues anyway. The sodium bisulfate is commonly available as the chemical used to lower pH in swimming pools, so it safer than using sulfuric acid. Stay safe!

Comment: @LeeHambley No, he doesn't and I don't see a way to know it for sure without checking specific product data (perhaps someone might know some generic proportion, though).